# Dust from footsteps

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I search since days, how i can simulate the dust from footsteps like when someone walks in the desert or on the moon.
Like in this video.
Please help:)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Using a [smoke simulation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/introduction.html) -

- Add a [smoke domain](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/types/domain.html) that encloses the area that is walked on.
- Add a small plane for each footstep and enable [smoke flow](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/types/flow_object.html) for each.
- Animate the density value of the flow, it should be zero until the frame you want a puff of smoke when you change it to one and then back to zero the next frame.
- Lower the temperature difference to stop it rising and add some [turbulence](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/force_fields/types/turbulence.html) to make it shift around.

[image: smokey steps]

Another approach might be to create particle emitters and use particles as the smoke source. I'm inclined to think this can give you more control. You may even want to try particles and use the [point density node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/textures/point_density.html).